# High bulk capacitance (100.000 uF) discharge time on Wifi router supply

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, router

I want a WiFi router, those supplied with 12V x 1~1.5A AC-DC wall adapter, to remain ON for a short time (maybe one second or a little more) after the AC mains gets its energy interrupted, when AC goes down.

One idea is to place 10x electrolytic caps of 10.000uF x 16V on the 12V output out the adapter (supply input of WiFi router), a nominal 100.000uF capacitance.

Is there a way to "have an idea" of the number of seconds the routers can remain ON after the AC goes down? And also for Wifi routers with integrated modem.

Comment: Yes, but it 100% depends on exactly two factors: 1. how much power the router needs at that point 2. how low an input voltage it can still work with. The rest is "capacitor discharge curve", and easy to google.

Comment: If the router actually takes 1A, 0.1F will droop 1V in 0.1 seconds (Q = I * t = C * V)

Comment: When you say "100.000" do you mean  "one hundred, very precisely" or do you mean "one hundred thousand"?

Comment: Chances are you will destroy the power supply when it turns on doing this. Your better with a battery backup etc .

Comment: I mean 100000uF, 100KuF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to "have an idea" of the number of seconds the routers
>   can remain ON after the AC goes down?

You want to hold the 12 volt DC on for a period of time using a capacitor so, the first limitation of this idea is that the voltage will instantly start to droop once the power is removed. But that isn't necessarily a show-stopper if the router can survive all the way down to 10 volts. It will be taking a roughly constant current as the capacitor is supplying the rapidly drooping voltage and this might be (say) 1 amp (just for numerical convenience).

The formula: -

$$I = C\dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

So, dv will be the change in voltage (say 2 volts) and dt will be the time allowed for it to droop (say 2 seconds). Hence: -

$$1\text{ amp} = C\dfrac{2\text{ volts}}{2\text{ seconds}}$$

Or, rearranging, C = 1 farad.

That's quite large (supercap sort of size) so pick carefully. If your current is only 100 mA then a 0.1 farad capacitor would hold up a drooping supply of 12 volts for 2 seconds. If only 1 second is required then 50,000 uF would do the job.

But, it all comes down to how low a voltage can you tolerate on your router before it gives up the ghost?

> *One idea is to place 10x electrolytic caps of 10.000uF x 16V on the
>   12V output out the adapter (supply input of WiFi router), a nominal
>   100.000uF capacitance.*

Very unlikely to be anywhere near enough. You are probably about a thousand times too small.

Comment: I suspect that "100.000" is European; in the US it would be "100,000". So about right, not a thousand times too small.